# Read POD data from binary file

Tags: vb.net

I have to read POD data from binary file and have problems with this. Most likely I dont know to use code at provided way. MyFile is of 1116 bytes long and contain propper data written by VB in DOS where I can read it successfully.
In showed example I would like to read first 65 bytes in every record. Bytes from 65 to 124 is not important here...

```
Public Structure recStruct
    Dim code As Short
    <VBFixedString(27)>Dim name As String
    <VBFixedString(16)>Dim kat As String
    <VBFixedString(16)>Dim bcode As String
    Dim price As Single
End Structure
''-------------------------------------------------

    Dim REC_SIZE As Integer = 124

    Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(myFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

        Dim f As Integer = CInt(fs.Length)
        Dim records As Integer = CInt(f / REC_SIZE)

        For t As Integer = 1 To records
            Dim seekpoint As Integer = (t - 1) * REC_SIZE

            '' on second step of loop when t=2
            '' program here breaks!

            fs.Seek(seekpoint, SeekOrigin.Begin)

            Using br As New BinaryReader(fs, New ASCIIEncoding())

                Dim s As New recStruct

                s.code = br.ReadInt16
                s.name = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(br.ReadBytes(27))

                '' here I would like to skip 32 bytes
                '' instead of reading 'kat' and 'bcode' members

                s.price = br.ReadSingle
            End Using
        Next t
    End Using
```

So Here I have two problems.
1) When t=1 I can read data from record OK, but when t increments program breaks on line 'fs.Seek(seekpoint, SeekOrigin.Begin)'.
2) How to skip desired number of bytes for rdon't loose the time on reading it if they are not needed?

How to get this working at expected way OR what do I do wrong here?

Comment: You say it breaks on the `fs.Seek(...)` line. So... What's the exception then??

Comment: Yes, I catch that exception. Because of End Using stream was closed. I fixed that now. Actually, with this a problem no. 1 was solved...

Comment: I didn't ask if you were _catching_ the exception, I asked _what kind of exception_ it was. But since you've solved it it doesn't matter any more.